# CSS change color of span when hovering over button

Tags: html, css

How would I select the span in this html to make the text in it white when hovering over the button?

```
<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle none" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Auckland" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
    <span class="multiselect-selected-text" style="visibility: visible;">Auckland</span>
    <b class="caret"></b>
</button>
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
button.multiselect > span:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change css like:

```
button.multiselect:hover > span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Because, You want hover effect on button

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L7fpgzc/)**